# Is there something like a P-clip but with symmetric flanges?

Tags: pipe, fastener

This is a P-clip:

[image: a black nylon P-clip]

It has a round bit which goes round a pipe, and two flanges which come off and present a pair of aligned holes through which you can thread a bolt. Ideal.

One of the flanges comes off the round bit at a tangent, and the other doubles back on itself to come off at a sharp angle. When bolted together, they form a projection which is tangential to the pipe - if you bolted through the flanges to a surface, that the pipe would lie pretty much flat on that surface. Since P-clips are mostly used for mounting pipes to walls, this is, again, ideal.

I have a situation where i want to bolt something to a pipe, but it's not a wall. I actually want to hang something off a pipe. To do this, i need some sort of clip where i can put a bolt through a projection which sticks straight out from the pipe, rather than sticking out at a tangent. Not a P-clip - more of a Q-clip.

(Would a diagram help here?)

Is there such a thing? I have searched for Q-clips, in case that's what they're called, but haven't come up with much.

Comment: How heavy is this hanging object going to be?  Pipes, while strong in and of themselves, were not installed with the idea of hanging things off them in mind.

Comment: If there is a cleaner looking solution than mine, I could see using it to make your own cabinet handles/pulls. I'm trying to make a 4' handle but want a few supports in that length.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore: I can reveal that the 'pipe' is in fact the upper part of a bicycle wishbone seatstay, and the thing i am 'hanging' from it is in fact a pair of mounting bracket arms for a bike rack (which don't bear load, but stabilise the rack in the fore-aft direction). I am confident that the 'pipe' will be strong enough.

Comment: @TomAnderson When the question says pipe certain disclaimers should be listed. Bike or water pipe you can do as you please but hopefully this question and answers will be helpful to others in the future so generic questions warrant generic disclaimers.

Comment: @Monso: Good point, sorry.

Comment: MS-AN name for this item you refer to as a P-clip is an Adel Clamp, used for securing hoses, harnesses, etc.

Comment: Adel Clamp is an insulated P-Clip made by [Adel Wiggins](http://adelwiggins.com/index-3.html).

Answer (score 2):

There are 'universal' pipe hangers that you could shape as needed. These are just a strip of malleable metal with a series of holes in it. I'm sure the big box stores have something equivalent.

[image: Pipe hanger]

http://www.mcmaster.com/#perforated-steel-straps/=nrz5k8

Adding some more options:

[image: Pipe Routing]
http://www.mcmaster.com/#pipe-routing-clamps/=nrzgqn

Comment: Aha. So what i'm looking for is probably a "pipe hanger" of some sort? That makes perfect sense - it's just upside-down to how i had been thinking.

Comment: Yep, Need to hold a something to a pipe. Figure out how people hold pipes to things. I've added more from McMaster, which is a great site to start your search for what mechanical bits exist.

Comment: the metal strips are sometimes called 'plumbers tape' ... but if this is going on a vertical pipe, you might need something that's going to hold more firmly, as it's generally used for hanging pipes from other supports.

Answer (score 1):

There is a ground clamp, though it will not be flush with the pipe ~1/4" standoff.

[image]

[Lowes Product Link](http://www.lowes.com/pd_46879-12704-770563L_0__?productId=3364652&N)

--Edit, adding addition items:

Single Eared O Clip:

[image]

Exhaust Clamp:

[image]

Pipe Rail Tie:

[image]

Comment: That's pretty close. But i need to be able to run a bolt perpendicular to the pipe, as you can with a P-clip, and it looks like this gives me either a bolt running away from the pipe (as at the top) or parallel to it (through that little hole at the top).

Comment: But the bolt is perpendicular to the pipe. The screw to tighten on the ground wire is perpendicular centered, the other bolts are perpendicular tangents.

Comment: Oh, duh, yes, of course. Sorry, i was fixated on the bit at the top!